# Is there an aggregate function AND / OR for boolean types in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given that I have a table like this

```
ID  X
1   TRUE
1   FALSE
2   FALSE
2   FALSE
```

I would like to achieve the following result:

```
ID  BOOL_OR(X)
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
```

That is , I want to `GROUP BY ID` and aggregate the boolean values of `X` using the boolean OR operator.

PostgreSQL has [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html)  that I can use like this

```
with t1 as
         (
             select *
             from (values (1, true)
                        , (1, false)
                        , (2, false)
                        , (2, false)) AS t1 (id, x)
         )
select id, bool_or(x)
from t1
group by id;
-- results
ID  BOOL_OR(X)
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
```

The same query in Snowflake SQL gives `SQL compilation error: Invalid identifier BOOL_OR`, which is **no surprise** since the [Snowflake documentation for Aggregate functions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-aggregation.html) does not list `BOOL_OR`.

So my question is there some other alternative way to get the same effects as PostgreSQL's `bool_or` and `bool_and` in Snowflake SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019-11-04**

Snowflake recently introduced [`BOOLOR_AGG`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/boolor_agg.html) and [`BOOLAND_AGG`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/booland_agg.html) functions that should provide the desired functionality.

**Original answer**

`MIN` and `MAX` functions in Snowflake seem to do what you would expect for booleans, with `MIN` working like `BOOL_AND / AND_AGG` and with `MAX` working like `BOOL_OR / OR_AGG`.

See this example:

```
create or replace table x(col1 boolean, col2 boolean, col3 boolean);
insert into x values(true, true, false),(true,false,false);
select * from x;
------+-------+-------+
 COL1 | COL2  | COL3  |
------+-------+-------+
 TRUE | TRUE  | FALSE |
 TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
------+-------+-------+

select min(col1),max(col1),min(col2),max(col2),min(col3),max(col3) from x;
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 MIN(COL1) | MAX(COL1) | MIN(COL2) | MAX(COL2) | MIN(COL3) | MAX(COL3) |
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
 TRUE      | TRUE      | FALSE     | TRUE      | FALSE     | FALSE     |
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Note, this does not seem to be officially documented though, so use at your own risk :)

Comment: The point of using `bool_and` is that it will compute faster for bigger groups. Imagine  that there are millions of book values in each group: `bool_or()` will decide that it evaluates to true as soon as it sees a one `true` value while `min()` needs (at least I think so) to scan all the values.

Comment: That's a fair comment, but doing this optimization (properly) in general case would be extremely complicated and I doubt any databases do it. You can of course stop processing bool_or or bool_and when you hit true or false, resp, but for example avoiding scanning the related column or computing the input expression would be very hard in most systems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a boolor() function in Snowflake, but it's not the same thing.  What you want to use is the Snowflake bitor_agg() function, which does the same logic, but on a bit value.  The function is a little awkward because it uses the integer equivalent of a boolean, rather than a boolean directly.  So, in your example:

```
with t1 as
         (
             select $1 as id, $2 as x
             from (values (1, true)
                        , (1, false)
                        , (2, false)
                        , (2, false)) AS t1
         )
select id, bitor_agg(x::integer)::boolean
from t1
group by id;
```

The conversion inside the function makes the values integer for the bitor_agg() function, and then the boolean conversion outside brings it back to boolean for you.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/bitor_agg.html

Comment: FYI - there is also bitand_agg() and bitxor_agg().

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose something much simpler:
Use `MAX` for `AND` and use `MIN` for `OR`.
Yes, you may have to cast the argument to ::integer but that's a small price to pay.

```
select   min(value::integer)::boolean,
         max(value::integer)::boolean,
         key
from     mytable
group by key;
```

Comment: I don’t think casting is the problem. The problem is that MAX and MIN needs to scan all values, and BOOLOR_AGG will finish as soon as a true value is found. If you are processing millions of rows this makes a difference.

Comment: MAX and MIN do not need to scan the entire data, as long as snowfkale has pre-computed SMAs for the columns.
And, even in the AND/OR case (which is *not* guaranteed to short-cut in SQL) the map/reduce execution will still need to split up the data across all executing nodes, and the savings from stopping the in-RAM execution can be quite small (unless you end up scanning thousands of micropartitions, without proper SMAs.)